Why the "$+1$" in $\sum_{x=\lceil u\rceil}^ne^{-f(x)}\leq\int_u^\infty e^{-f(x)} \; dx + 1$?
So I have been reading Lattimore's book on Bandit Algorithms, and while proving the lemma for Asymptotic UCB, he bounds the sum of $e^{-f(x)}$ as follows:
$$\sum\limits_{x = \lceil u \rceil}^{n} e^{-f(x)} \leq \int_{u}^\infty e^{-f(x)} \; dx + 1$$
I do not understand where the $+1$ comes from. Maybe it comes from the fact that $e^{-f(u)} = 1$, which I understand, but why does it need to be added?
When I was checking various values on Desmos and using some Python simulations, I found that the $+1$ is not necessary if the fractional part of $u$ is between $0$ and $0.5$. However, if the fractional part is greater than $0.5$, then the bound fails to hold without the $+1$.
Am I missing something, since I always thought bounding a finite summation by an infinite integral can be done blindly?

What are the assumptions on $f$?

No assumptions: $f(x) = \frac{x(b-\sqrt{\frac{b^2u}{x}})}{2}$

If $f$ is monotonically increasing and the sum is convergent, then
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{x = \left\lceil u \right\rceil }^n {{\rm e}^{ - f(x)} } & = {\rm e}^{ - f(\left\lceil u \right\rceil )}  + \sum\limits_{x = \left\lceil u \right\rceil  + 1}^n {\int_{x - 1}^x {{\rm e}^{ - f(x)} {\rm d}t} } \\ & \le {\rm e}^{ - f(\left\lceil u \right\rceil )}  + \sum\limits_{x = \left\lceil u \right\rceil  + 1}^n {\int_{x - 1}^x {{\rm e}^{ - f(t)} {\rm d}t} } \\ & \le {\rm e}^{ - f(\left\lceil u \right\rceil )}  + \sum\limits_{x = \left\lceil u \right\rceil  + 1}^{  \infty } {\int_{x - 1}^x {{\rm e}^{ - f(t)} {\rm d}t} }  \\ &= {\rm e}^{ - f(\left\lceil u \right\rceil )}  + \int_{\left\lceil u \right\rceil }^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - f(t)} {\rm d}t} \\ & \le {\rm e}^{ - f(u)}  + \int_u^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - f(t)} {\rm d}t} \\ & = 1 + \int_u^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - f(t)} {\rm d}t} .
\end{align*}
In the opposite direction:
$$
\sum\limits_{x = \left\lceil u \right\rceil }^n {{\rm e}^{ - f(x)} }  \ge \sum\limits_{x = \left\lceil u \right\rceil }^n {\int_x^{x + 1} {{\rm e}^{ - f(t)} {\rm d}t} }  = \int_{\left\lceil u \right\rceil }^{ n+1 } {{\rm e}^{ - f(t)} {\rm d}t} .
$$
If $u$ is an integer, you can see that the $+1$ is needed.
This technique is used in proving the integral test, see the remark here.

Thanks a lot, Ill read the general proof on Wiki as well for a more general intuition!

We might simplify the argument by writing $g(x)$ instead of $e^{-f(x)}$ and then assuming that $g$ is decreasing etc.

The reason for this adjustment lies in the behavior of the exponential function. When the fractional part of  is less than 0.5, the sum of exponential terms over a finite range closely approximates the integral over the same range. However, when the fractional part of  is greater than 0.5, the sum tends to underestimate the integral, and adding 1 compensates for this discrepancy.
In other words, the +1 term ensures that the bound holds for all possible values of , maintaining the asymptotic optimality of the UCB algorithm. It’s not something you can blindly omit; it’s a crucial adjustment to make the bound accurate.

I see, is there any way to see this in a more mathematical fashion?
